# Defining and calling function in Haskell FP Complete online IDE

Tags: haskell

Is this not the correct way to define a function in fpcenter in Haskell ? :

```
-- | Main entry point to the application.
module Main where

-- | The main entry point.
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome to FP Haskell Center!"
    putStrLn "Have a good day!"


let exp x n | n == 0 = 1
 | n == 0 = 1
 | n == 1 = x
 | even n = exp (x * x) m
 | odd n = x * exp (x*x) (m-1)
where m = n `div` 2
```

It displays `src/Main.hs@12:2-12:3 parse error on input |` at line      `| n == 0 = 1`

The function is correctly defined when added to Prelude.

Update : error message screenshot attached -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` is not used for top-level bindings (look at `main`). Simply write:

```
exp x n
 | n == 0 = 1
 | n == 1 = x
 | even n = exp (x * x) m
 | odd n = x * exp (x * x) (m - 1)
 where m = n `div` 2
```

Also, when you do use `let` or `let`-`in`, it follows the same layout rules as `do` for its block of bindings—the block must be indented as much as the first item in the block. People usually indent things in one of two ways:

```
let
  a = 2
  f x y
   | x < y = x
   | otherwise = y

let a = 2
    f x y | x < y = x
          | otherwise = y
```

I prefer the former style, because it does not require changing whitespace as often.

Comment: @blue-sky: You also need to indent the `where` clause by at least one space.

Comment: @blue-sky there's an extra `=` in the screenshot in the line `exp x n`

Comment: @Jon Purdy exp is a reserved function at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:exp so I receive error "Ambiguous occurrence exp
It could refer to either Main.exp,
                         defined at /home/app/isolation-runner-work/projects/84897/session.207/src/src/Main.hs:14:1
                      or Prelude.exp," When I rename to "exp2" it compiles